# Rendering different partials in same div

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a few buttons like this:

```
<div class="button" id="picture-button">
<div class="button" id="text-button">
<div class="button" id="video-button">
```

I then have some JS:

```
$('.button').click(function () {
    $('.modal').toggle('slide', {
        direction: 'top'
    }, 300);
});
```

and a modal that the buttons open up:

```
<div class="modal">
  <%= render 'picture_form' %>
</div>
```

The problem is the rendered partial has to correspond to the button clicked eg. picture-button renders picture-form. Is there an easier way to do this than having separate modals and js for each partial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, rendering is done server-side before your user gets the page, so your use-case isn't possible. What you should do is either use an AJAX call to query the server for the data to put in the modal when a user clicks the corresponding button, or simply render it all at once as different modals, and only show the one the user clicks on.

For example, have three div modals with ID `#button1, #button2, #button3` and on button click show whichever corresponds to the button.

Comment: Ok, I'll render them separately. Thanks for the help.